# Datepicker in ASP.NET: error in browser IE8 about jquery "Cannot read property 'msie'" without having $.browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using ASP.NET.

I need to create a datepicker.
I read on [http://jqueryui.com/](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) how do that and it works.

In particular, the code is the following:

```
   <input id="date_picker" type="date" />
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#date_picker').datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, minDate: 0, changeYear: true });
        });

    </script>
```

I included:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.widget.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/metro.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" />
```

Only the last one is related to datepicker.

I also included:

```
<link id="link1" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" type="text/css" />
<link id="link2" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

Now, the problem is that:

Everything works with chrome as browser, but I noticed that with Developer Tools (F12) an error occurred (the error is in the screenshot: [image]).

The application must be able to work also in Internet Explorer 8. Of course with those errors it generates a pop up with the error and the datepicker doesn't work.

Where am I wrong?

I read others post about that but I'm not using $.browser so I don't know how to fix that.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have two references to jQuery?

<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />

Comment: Because jquery.version.js is different from jquery.version.min.js, isn't it? I used them for others stuff in the application.

Comment: They are different but they will cause major headaches. You should never reference jquery twice, even if they are different versions, as you will get javascript errors.

Comment: I noted that jquery-1.11.1.min.js is in conflict with jquery.ui.datepicker.js",  so I removed jquery.ui.datepicker.js".

Comment: The problem with Explorer 8 still persists. In this browser the datepicker doesn't work and there isn't F12 to check.. what can I do?

Comment: IE8 has developer tools! Just press F12 or go to IE->tools->developer tools

Comment: It is setted in IE->tools->developer tools but doesn't work! There is another (empty) instance of a page IE8, nothing more. I can't see anything  (because of that I tought there wasn't a tool!!)